# First occurrence of element in an array using pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int findFirst(const string a[], int n, string target)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 if (a[i] == target)
 return i;
return -1;
}
```

How do I write the above program without using square brackets and using the following function header?

```
int findFirst(const string* a, int n, string target)
```

Comment: You can access the element at a by using (*a == target). Then you can increment a by using means of pointer arithmetic. a++ will automatically point to the next char.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the function header; `const string a[]` already is a pointer parameter and means exactly the same as `const string* a`.

Then, you can either dereference `a + i`

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (*(a + i) == target)
```

or increment `a` along with `i`

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, a++)
    if (*a == target)
```

or you could use only pointers

```
for (const string* p = a; p < a + n; p++)
    if (*p == target)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you write a function that have a pointer as an input parameter it would be better to check this pointer on nullptr (or 0):

```
int findFirst(const string * a, int n, string target)
{
  if (a)
  {
    // do search
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Second, for searching the item position you can use algorithms from Standard Library:

```
#include <algorithm>

int findFirst(const std::string* a, int n, std::string target)
{
    if (a)
    {
        int res = std::distance(a, std::find(a, a + n, target));
        if (res < n)
        {
            return res;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Third, it would be better to pass the target by const reference to exclude unnecessary call of copy constructor. And as a result we can have the following final solution:

```
#include <algorithm>

int findFirst(const std::string* a, int n, const std::string& target)
{
    if (a)
    {
        int res = std::distance(a, std::find(a, a + n, target));
        if (res < n)
        {
            return res;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```